# Get size of IBOutlet UIImageView

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiimageview, size, iboutlet

I need to get the size of an IBOutlet UIImageView drawn in Interface Builder.

But if I read the IBOutlet UIIMageView.image.size.width or .height in the viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method I always get 0 !!!

Where (which method) and how (may be an other variable ?) can I get this information ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 11):

does

```
UIImageView *iv;  
width = iv.frame.size.width;
```

work any better?  Instead of the image, get the size of the UIImageView.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for information !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: What's the difference between `iv.frame.size.width` and `iv.frame.width`?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the size value, if "Use Autolayout" option in file inspector is unchecked